# Matlab: Contruct Random Forest Model for Training and Label Vectors

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest

I am trying to construct a Random Forest Model for the 12 extracted feature vectors and 1 Label Vector in my problem. I am having alot of problems in the following line

```
  B = TreeBagger(nTrees,TrainingVector,LabelVector, 'Method', 'classification');
```

The size of `TrainingVector` is `8519680x12` and its in `uint16` and the size of `LabelVector` is `8519680x1` and its in `uint8`. I am using 10 number of trees i.e. `nTree`. After i set all the parameters of `TreeBagger` and execute the above line i get the following error.

```
Error using ClassificationTree.prepareData (line 757)
             X must be a floating-point matrix.

Error in TreeBagger/init (line 1055)
            [bagger.X,y,bagger.W,bagger.DataSummary,classSummary] = ...

Error in TreeBagger (line 482)
            bagger = init(bagger,X,Y,makeArgs{:});

Error in tumor (line 128)
           B = TreeBagger(nTrees,TrainingVector,LabelVector, 'Method', 'classification');
```

Kindly guide me in the explained scenario. Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: What type of data are you training?

Comment: try `B = TreeBagger(nTrees,double(TrainingVector),double(LabelVector), 'Method', 'classification');` since the error says your data should be in floating point.

Comment: @BibekSubedi am extracting 12 feature vector for the voxel values of a 3D mri sequence in mha format.

Comment: @Parag yes its helpful but since i am using 12 feature vectors each of size around 8000,000. I need to do some sort of feature reduction and selection, any ideas?

Comment: @NajeebullahShah use `single` instead of `double`, it uses 4 bytes. Also, your data is not too big, your fature matrix with single precision takes only 0.3 GB of space.

Comment: @Parag Yes but the data is only for 3,4 instances. I have 80 such instances for feature set.